# Subtracting different values from each related raster file with iterate field values tool in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, raster-calculator, iteration

I must extract values by point (just one point) from multiple TIFF format rasters and then multiply these values with -1 and add them to the raster files with raster calculator.  As what you can see in image using  iterate field values helps me to extract raster value from its shapefile and the procedure will go on but 3 item must identify manually (red lines) and it takes time.

What do I need to do for the red lines parts to do this with an iterator?

[image]